# Select2 dropdown value stored, But not showing in UI

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

## This image shows the value showing in dropdown, but not in the input field.

the value is not showing till i click the options.
[image]

## this image shows that the value is stored as an array, but not showing in UI.

[image]

## This is what i was expecting to be shown. Please help me, Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of the way you create the select2